# Bootstrap Dropdown toggle triggered from javascript won't stay open consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D56q7/7/)
The fiddle works as intended using the same exact code from my site! Copy and pasted.

[My site](http://daronspence.com/newsite/)

To replicate this issue you have to do these steps exactly. Go to a fresh load of the page. Scroll to the bottom and click "Contact" in the middle column. Now when you try and select the `form` options, the dropdown closes. Why is this happening? The fiddle has the exact same code, JS and all. On a fresh load, the toggle button by itself works as intended. Once the "contact" link is brought in, it breaks.

Here is the custom script I wrote to scroll to the top and open the dropdown.

```
// Scroll To Top and Open Contact Form -->
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $('#nav-contact.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
  return false;
}); 
<!--// End Contact Form Scripts -->
```

I don't really know any JS but I'm trying to learn to put this site together as a personal project for enrichment. Any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Ideas?

Comment: The Fiddle ins't working anymore :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsfiddle working fine for me too, but you could actually try like this,

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function (e) {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow", function () {
        $('#nav-contact.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
    });
    return false;
});
```

calling the `toggle` within the callback.